# How can I get Referrer URL with PHP?

Tags: php, url, referrer

How can I get Referrer URL with PHP but the DIRECTORY only not the whole link (so without http://domain.com/) only the directory?

e.g:

```
Referrer: /contact/user/9443/
```

but **not** this

```
http://domain.com/contact/user/9443/
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have PHP installed at the moment, but you could try using [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). This **should** do it I think:

```
parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking for is the referrer's path, which may or may not be on the current site, so in general you don't want to take only that.

afaik there's no special referrer-path for you; just parse out the path like so:

```
$referer_path = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: Hello, there yes that worked for me if i only could mark your answer ALSO as an accepted answer, THANK YOU.